# Programmatically start process in old Windows Terminal?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, windows-terminal

My c++ application requires opening and closing terminal windows and complex terminal manipulation.  It does not work in the new windows terminal with the tab system. I don't want to force users to change their default terminal just to run my app. I have code to check if my app is in the new terminal and if so I want to start a new copy in the old terminal then exit the current one. Unfortunately cmd.exe still starts the new terminal.
How do I launch an application using the old windows terminal?

```
void StartInOldTerminal() {
    // Get path of current executable
    wchar_t exePath[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, exePath, MAX_PATH) == 0) {
        // Failed to get executable path, handle error
        std::cerr << "Failed to get executable path\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    // Check if running in the new Windows Terminal
    DWORD consoleMode;
    if (GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &consoleMode) == 0) {
        // Failed to get console mode, handle error
        std::cerr << "Failed to get console mode\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((consoleMode & ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING) != 0) {
        std::wstring cmdWStr = L"cmd.exe /k \"" + std::wstring(exePath) + L"\""; //Still starts in new terminal
        std::string cmdStr = Text::wstring_to_utf8(cmdWStr);
        system(cmdStr.c_str());
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "old" and "new" Windows Terminal. Is that a Windows 11 thing?

Comment: @paddy https://www.ghacks.net/2021/12/17/command-prompt-to-be-replaced-by-windows-terminal-in-windows-11/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a secret - you can manually launch the vintage console with the commandline `conhost.exe`. By default, it'll spawn a `cmd.exe` instance to run inside it, but you can also tell it to launch something else by just doing `conhost.exe -- powershell.exe`.

So, in your case, try prepending `conhost.exe --`  to your `cmdWStr`.

---

I will note though, that looking for `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` will not strictly tell you that a commandline application is running in the Terminal (vs conhost). Any commandline application can set that (and I believe that `pwsh.exe` does by default, even outside the Terminal). Nor is there an environment variable to check if you're in the Terminal (because the Terminal does not always have the opportunity to set such a variable).

If you do have a complex scenario that's not working in the Terminal, the team would love to hear about it over at https://github.com/microsoft/terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying to start conhost.exe in my app causes windows to flag my program as a virus and disable it.

Comment: This is very useful. I use to to launch multiple instances of microemacs without having to have a cmd.exe for each.  Is there a way to control the size of the window?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/definitions

is not helpful I think.

Comment: Some other requests to identify whether running in the new windows terminal suggested checking for the WT_SESSION env variable.  I have noticed that this isn't foolproof, as it could be set by a windows terminal session that later spawned your non-wt application. (Of course they're currently suggesting not to do this due to numerous potential issues, https://github.com/Textualize/rich/issues/140 , but generally applicable alternatives are still lacking)